# How to use ggplot in R to create a single graphic comprised of a bar plot and a line plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to using qplot and ggplot, and basically want to make a figure that is just the combination of a bar plot and a line plot. I can do one or the other, but don't know how to do both at once!

Here is my data:

```
bulk = data.frame(x_pos=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 
    y_line=c(3,7,6,8,14,16,18,12),
    y_bar=c(0,0,10,0,0,0,10,0))
```

For a line graph, I just do `qplot(x_pos, y_line, data=bulk, geom="line")`
For a bar plot, I just do `qplot(x_pos, y_bar, data=bulk)`

But! How can I combine these at once into a single figure?? My real intention is to use several (maybe 6-10) different graphics techniques like this to generate complex figures, but it all starts with knowing how to do two at once. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `qplot` for this.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(bulk, aes(x=x_pos)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=y_bar), stat="identity") +
  geom_line(aes(y=y_line), color="red", size=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, but can you please explain to me what `aes` does, as well as `stat="identity"`?

Comment: `aes` defines aesthetic mappings and `stat="identity"` overrides the default `stat="bin"` in `geom_bar` since your data is already binned. All of this is explained in the documentation.